# Create a sort of parallelogram in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drawing

How can I create this sort of parallelogram in Illustrator ?

[image]

Comment: The Skew Tool, Free Transform Tool, etc.. What have you tried?

Comment: @Scott Shear not Skew. This is Sparta! Er um I mean illustrator.

Comment: @Ryan ... meh.. blame Adobe for not naming the the tools universal names across apps :)

Comment: I have found the easiest way to do this is just use the direct selection tool to simply click the top anchor points (both selected) and hit the arrow keys until you have a nice skew.. erm... shear :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have sorta tried to say you can use the Shear tool (Skew is in Photoshop).

Shear Tool location:

[image: Shear Tool]

And usage:

[image: Shear Tool Usage]

**Other Option**

What I would be more likely to do is the Direct Selection Tool (White Arrow) and pick two points on a single side of the primitive shape.

[image: Direct Selection]

Then either up arrow, down arrow, left arrow, or right arrow (or mouse if you prefer) to get the desired result. For this depiction I used the down arrow.

[image: Direct Selection Result]

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the skew tool on a rectangle you can:

1) Draw any line, using the line tool or even the pen tool.

2) Duplicate that line using Alt (Option in Macs) and making sure it's aligned by holding the Shift key while dragging.

3) Make it a parallelogram by adding straight lines to the sides.

It's not exactly the most practical and it's not as fast as shearing, but it might be useful for something like this:

[image: colorful lines yay]

But yeah, making a rectangle and shearing it using the transform tool is also valid.